How to get onPress to work on Callout inside PointAnnotation or MarkerView (rnmapbox)
i was trying to make a touchable popup, but i couldn't get it to work using either PointAnnotation or MarkerView.
Using PointAnnotation:
<Mapbox.PointAnnotation
                    key={marker.id}
                    id={marker.id}
                    coordinate={marker.coord}
                    title={marker.additionalInfo.name}
                    onSelected={() => {
                        setHasToFollowUser(true)
                        camera.current?.setCamera({
                            zoomLevel: 18,
                            animationMode: 'flyTo',
                            centerCoordinate: marker.coord
                        })
                        setHasToFollowUser(false)
                    }}
                >
                        <FontAwesome5 
                            name='map-marker-alt' 
                            size={markerProperDim} 
                            color={color} 
                        />
                        <Mapbox.Callout title="">
                            <PointPopUp
                                img={marker.additionalInfo.img}
                                title={marker.additionalInfo.name}
                                subtitle={marker.additionalInfo.relatedAssetName}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AssetScreen', { id: marker.id, type: marker.type })}
                            />
                        </Mapbox.Callout>
                </Mapbox.PointAnnotation>

Using MarkerView:
 <Mapbox.MarkerView
                    key={marker.id}
                    id={marker.id}
                    coordinate={marker.coord}
                    // title={marker.additionalInfo.name}
                    onTouchEnd={() => {
                        setHasToFollowUser(true)
                        camera.current?.setCamera({
                            zoomLevel: 18,
                            animationMode: 'flyTo',
                            centerCoordinate: marker.coord
                        })
                        setHasToFollowUser(false)
                    }}
                >
                    <>
                        <FontAwesome5 
                            name='map-marker-alt' 
                            size={markerProperDim} 
                            color={color} 
                        />
                        <Mapbox.Callout title="">
                            <PointPopUp
                                img={marker.additionalInfo.img}
                                title={marker.additionalInfo.name}
                                subtitle={marker.additionalInfo.relatedAssetName}
                                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AssetScreen', { id: marker.id, type: marker.type })}
                            />
                        </Mapbox.Callout>
                    </>
                </Mapbox.MarkerView>

Obs:

MarkerView doesn't render FontAwesome icon
I've wrapped the elements inside an empty fragment because "MarkerView" only accepts one children
I'm using FontAwesome5 element to make a custom marker

